# lightning-tab align align center

Tags: css, lightning-tab, lightning-tabset

I have only two tabs in lightning-tabset. And its align left. I need to have it in center. I tried padding-left: 200px; on ".slds-tabs" but nothing seems to be working. It works when i change through inspect element. But Nothings happening when i add code in componet's .css file.

here is playground's link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/BZGvQu4nV/8/edit

Is there any cleaner approach without using padding?
I know its very basic and silly question. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Manohar

Comment: do u need tab label or content to be center?

Comment: @salesforce-sas tab label to be centered.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I try to avoid lwc components as soon as custom css is involved because of restrictions imposed by [**shadow dom**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_dom)

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/gminero/3fd4a4168a8903a9c9d900e3801855a3) leverages the [slds tabs blueprint](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tabs/)

I simply declared the .tab-container as flex, aligned the items to center, and each li item is also self centered.

example.html

```
<div class="slds-tabs_default">
    <ul class="slds-tabs_default__nav tab-container" role="tablist">
        <li class="slds-tabs_default__item slds-is-active" title="Item One" role="presentation" onclick={tabClick}>
        <a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tab-default-1" id="tab-default-1__item">Item One</a>
        </li>
        <li class="slds-tabs_default__item" title="Item Two" role="presentation" onclick={tabClick}>
        <a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-default-2" id="tab-default-2__item">Item Two</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-default-1" class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-1__item">Item One Content</div>
    <div id="tab-default-2" class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-hide" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-2__item">Item Two Content</div>
</div>
```

(sample method to toggle css classes for activating tabs - you can easily achieve the same for the content tabs)

example.js

```
    tabClick(e){
      const allTabs = document.querySelectorAll('ul>li');
      allTabs.forEach( (elm, idx) =>{
          console.log(elm);
          elm.classList.remove("slds-is-active")
      })
    e.currentTarget.classList.add('slds-is-active')
}
```

example.css

```
.tab-container {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}
.tab-container li{
  align-self: center;
}
```

Preview:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a similar scenario and I followed the post but I couldn't switch the body  of tab set just the header kept on changing. So I have modified the solution and used the **slds-grid** to align the headers.

**HTML**

```
 <template>
<div class="slds-tabs_default">
    <ul class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-tabs_default__nav tab-container" role="tablist">
        <li class="slds-col slds-tabs_default__item slds-is-active" title="Item One" role="presentation" onclick={tabClick}>
            <a class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-tabs_default__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tab-default-1" id="tab-default-1__item">Item One</a>
        </li>
        <li class="slds-col slds-tabs_default__item" title="Item Two" role="presentation" onclick={tabClick}>
            <a class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-tabs_default__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-default-2" id="tab-default-2__item">Item Two</a>
        </li>
        <li class="slds-col slds-tabs_default__item" title="Item Two" role="presentation" onclick={tabClick}>
            <a class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-tabs_default__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-default-3" id="tab-default-3__item">Item Three</a>
        </li>
        <li class="slds-col slds-tabs_default__item" title="Item Two" role="presentation" onclick={tabClick}>
            <a class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-tabs_default__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-default-4" id="tab-default-4__item">Item Four</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-default-1" class="tab-default-1 slds-tabs_default__content slds-show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-1__item">Item One Content</div>
    <div id="tab-default-2" class="tab-default-2 slds-tabs_default__content slds-hide" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-2__item">Item Two Content</div>
    <div id="tab-default-3" class="tab-default-3 slds-tabs_default__content slds-hide" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-3__item">Item Three Content</div>
    <div id="tab-default-4" class="tab-default-4 slds-tabs_default__content slds-hide" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-4__item">Item Four Content</div>
</div>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class TabsetBasic extends LightningElement {
 tabClick(e) {
    const allTabs = this.template.querySelectorAll('.slds-tabs_default__item');
    allTabs.forEach((elm, idx) => {
        elm.classList.remove("slds-is-active");
    });
    e.currentTarget.classList.add('slds-is-active');
    var element = e.currentTarget.firstChild.id;

    var selectedelementarea = element.substr(0, element.indexOf('_'));;

    const tabview = this.template.querySelectorAll('.slds-tabs_default__content');
    tabview.forEach((elm, idx) => {
        elm.classList.remove("slds-show");
        elm.classList.add("slds-hide");
    });
    this.template.querySelector(`.${selectedelementarea}`).classList.remove("slds-hide");
    this.template.querySelector(`.${selectedelementarea}`).classList.add("slds-show");

 }
}
```

**RESULT**

[image]